# How do you explicitly name an Output in Dagster?

Tags: dagster

I have the following asset in Dagster:

```py
@asset
def some_asset():
    
    output = "some_great_output"

    return Output(
        value=output,
    )
```

As it is above, Dagster will name the materialization of this asset "result", the default name for outputs - not a very useful default name. Hence, I tried to change the output name by specifying the appropriate parameter of the `Output` object:

```py
@asset
def some_asset():
    
    output = "some_great_output"

    return Output(
        value=output,
        output_name=some_name,
    )
```

You would expect that this does the trick, right? It doesn't. This is the error it raises:

```
dagster._core.errors.DagsterInvariantViolationError: Bad state: Output was explicitly named 'some_name', which does not match the output definition specified for position 0: 'result'.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Not a super-straightforward way at the moment. You could do something like this:

```
@op(out={"some_great_output": Out()})
def my_op():
    return Output(
        value=5,
        output_name="some_great_output",
    )


my_asset = AssetsDefinition.from_op(
    my_op, keys_by_output_name={"some_great_output": AssetKey("my_asset_key")}
)
```

The `keys_by_output_name` arg is optional. If not provided, the output name is inferred to be the output asset key.

Wondering why you want to change the output name though? The materialization will output for `AssetKey("some_asset")`, and you'll be able to reference the output as a dependency using the asset key in any downstream assets.